# Paste to next available cell in column only works intermittently

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hoping someone can help with the below coding please?

The first section works perfectly every time, but the 2nd section (even though it's a replica, with only source and destination cells updated), only works intermittently.

```
  // Copy & Paste Selected Hashtags to "Hashtag Records" Tab
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Hashtag Records'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Hashtag Selector\'!K5:K50').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
// Copy & Paste Dates as Values within "Hashtag Records" Tab
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Hashtag Records'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Hashtag Selector\'!O5:O50').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);`
```

What's intended:

- The sections (part of a greater sequence) should copy 2 sets of data from source "Hashtag Tracker" to destination "Hashtag Records" within the same Google spreadsheet
- The data includes

1. A list of hashtags that are to be pasted to the next available cell in column B **This coding works perfectly every time**
2. Dates that are to be pasted to the next available cell in column A **This coding was replicated from the above (with source and destination cells updated)... but it only works intermittently** - sometimes it correctly pastes the dates to the next available cell, other times it pastes way down column A instead (unable to identify a pattern for the inconsistency)

I've tried different coding from both here and various online forums (I'm pretty sure the above was copied from here), but I've spent too much time trying to get it to work consistently, and would really appreciate some help please?

I'm not overly familiar with scripts, so I'm open to alternative coding if there's a better option... but there are formulas in the remaining columns that need to be taken into account (ie the entire row is not empty where the data needs to be pasted - only columns A and B are totally blank).

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

I find all of the "Activate" stuff a result of using a recorded macro and is not required.  In my opinion good Google Spreadsheet App Script program is done using the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).  Spreadsheet Service uses an instance of a Spreadsheet object and it methods to manipulate data.  I use `let` instead of `var`.

Here is how I would do it.

```
// Copy & Paste Selected Hashtags to "Hashtag Records" Tab
let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let dest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Hashtag Records");  // destination sheet
let source = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Hashtag Selector");  // source sheet
let range = dest.getRange("B1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);  // last filled row of column B
range = range.offset(1,0);  // next empty cell
source.getRange("K5:K50").copyTo(range,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);

// Copy & Paste Dates as Values within "Hashtag Records" Tab
range = dest.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);  // last filled row of column A
range = range.offset(1,0);  // next empty cell
source.getRange("O5:O50").copyTo(range,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response! Thank you for the above. I've given this a try, and it results in the same issue as the original formula unfortunately, with the dates being intermittently pasted further down the page

Comment: I suspect either your destination sheet has some date in column A or B that is causing the pasted data to be seperated by what appears to be empty rows.  Or the source data has some values in K5:K50 or O5:O50 that are not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array with dates and tags, and [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function to append that array to the target sheet, like this:

```js
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hashtag Records');
  const sourceData = ss.getRange('Hashtag Selector!K5:O50')
    .getValues()
    .map(row => [row[4], row[0],]);
  appendRows_(targetSheet, sourceData, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, and apologies for the delay in getting back to you! I'm not following your solution, sorry. Is additional information needed for it to work? It currently results in an error. Also, if rows are appended, would existing formulas in columns C- L then be lost?

Comment: You need to paste the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function in your script project.